# tabindex in CSS

Tags: html, css, keydown

Is it possible to control tabindex with CSS and if yes, which browsers support it and on which elements?

**EDIT**

I should say, my goal is to catch keydown events on a div. I saw this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events/keys.html# that tests keyboard events and it shows that the only way keydown fires on anything other than document and body or some kind of form element or link is to have tabindex declared on it. But I read on W3C site:

> The following elements support the
>   tabindex attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON,
>   INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

So I am a little confused, what to do in order to be standarts compliant and make my use case work?

**EDIT2**

My whole use case is a div with a lot of content with an artificial scroll bar. I am able to scroll it with mouse events but no luck with the keyboard so far.

Comment: Catching keyboard events on the div is not your use case. It is an implementation detail of you attempt to answer the use case. Answer it differently. (We can't give you much advice on how because you haven't told us what the real use case is).

Answer (score 31):

**Update 2017**

As pointed out by @Wallop in the comments, the `nav-index` property was [dropped from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-css-ui-3-20150707/#changes-since-2012) in 2015 due to "lack of implementation interest".

---

Take a look at the `nav-index` property introduced by W3C in [CSS3-UI](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#nav-index0).

This property has exactly the same behavior as a `tabindex` and is applicable to any element.

> The ‘nav-index’ property is an input-method-neutral way of specifying the sequential navigation order (also known as "tabbing order").
>   This property is a replacement for the HTML4/XHTML1 attribute ‘tabindex’

Being probably the best standards-compliant solution for the use case, `nav-index` is interpreted only by Opera so far (as of June 2012) and is also marked as "Feature at risk" by W3C, therefore may be dropped any time.

Alternative cross-browser solutions are:

- non-standards-compliant: set the `tabindex` attribute on a `DIV`. This will work in all common browsers.
- standards-compliant: replace `DIV` by an anchor element (`A`) without a `href` attribute set, style it with `display: block` and add the `tabindex` attribute.

With respect to BoltClock´s point, I agree that the tabbing order is very logical (both the text selection order and tabbing order are closely related to the sequence in which elements are aranged in the document). On the other hand, CSS has a wider purpose today. It can manipulate not just the content of a document (`content` property) but also the behavior when and if events are to be fired: i.e. using `pointer-events`, `display` or `z-index` the pointer event's order will change. If these are very basic CSS properties, why you should not be able to influence KeyBoardEvents, too?

Comment: I hear `tabindex` is now allowed on all elements in HTML5... for some reason.

Comment: As of April 2014, `nav-index` still has relatively no browser support. :(

Comment: @JeremyWest `nav-index` sounds good, but seems to [still not be supported](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) by any browser.

Comment: nav-index is now deprecated and no new browsers support it. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_nav-index.asp

Comment: nav-index is not completely dropped, "Dropped the nav-index property due to lack of implementation interest." as per https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#nav-index0

Comment: The spec has been updated. For anyone still interested, the cited text is now to be found in [the Candidate Recommendation 20150707](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-css-ui-3-20150707/#changes-since-2012)

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit old but now there are css options like -moz-user-focus. I'm sure there is a webkit equivalent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-user-focus

`user-focus` is the standard cross browser attribute.

Comment: It's just I was having the same issue and wanted to answer it with the way the user asked it. These stackoverflow topics come up a long on bing and google so i wanted to add the answer in here.

Comment: @SamB set `-moz-user-focus: none` or `-moz-user-focus: -moz-none` or `user-focus: none` on your element. `user-focus` is the standardized way.

Comment: Does it support setting a specific index for the focus? I don't see anything about it in the spec, maybe it's tab index will be determined by its location in the dom.

Comment: @miir to set a certain tabindex you have to use the html attribute I think.

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the question in any way, as `-moz-user-focus` only controls whether element is focusable, not it's tabbing order, which is what the question was about.

Comment: This also works on [Firefox ONLY](https://caniuse.com/#search=user-focus).

Comment: @Laoujin `user-focus` is the non-firefox attribute.

Comment: @Noitidart Can you please provide proof that `user-focus` is a standard? I can't find documentation to support your assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable focus with keyboard, which `pointer-events: none` would not help me with. I ended up using this as a good enough workaround:

```css
.not-focusable {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.not-focusable:focus {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This seem to work good enough, screen readers do not announce that momentary focus and it barely ever blinks for a moment.